# show feedback only when asked

Tags: php, css, hide, show

I'm creating a feedback. I show the success message when it's good and error when there is something wrong, but my css (red and green block) is there from the beginning. How can I hide this before there is feedback?

```
<div id="feedback_success">
    <?php if(empty($feedback_success)) { ?>
        <h1 ></h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1><?php echo $feedback_success ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="feedback_error">
    <?php if(empty($feedback_error)) { ?>
        <h1 ></h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1><?php echo $feedback_error ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

css

```
#feedback_success
{
    background-color: #45e589;
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:1.0em;
}


#feedback_error
{
    background-color: #ff5555;
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
```

Comment: #feedback_success
{
 background-color: #45e589;
 color: white;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:1.0em;
}


#feedback_error
{
 background-color: #ff5555;
 color: white;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:1.2em;
}

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the `id` according to whether it's successful and put the relevant message within a P tag, not the incorrect H1 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to do this

```
<?php if(!empty($feedback_success)): ?>
    <div id="feedback_success">
        <h1><?php echo $feedback_success ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($feedback_error)): ?>
    <div id="feedback_error">
        <h1><?php echo $feedback_error ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```